# FFMPEG Why is this output missing 8 columns of pixels?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, resolution

Absolutely no idea what is going on here.  Very annoying though.  Using ffmpeg-python...image.jpg is 1920x1080

```
image = ffmpeg.input('image.jpg', loop=1)
out = ffmpeg.output(image, 'out.mp4', t=1)
out.run()
```

When I right click on out.mp4 in Windows Explorer and click Details, it says the resolution is 1920x1072?  That makes no sense.  When I run ffprobe out.mp4, it says the resolution is 1920x1080.  However, I think ffprobe is actually wrong here.  Because when I append out.mp4 to another mp4 file, that is 1920x1080, there is a strange glitch (unexpected black screen for ~1 second) at the time where the videos are concatenated.  I think that is because they are different resolutions...(even though they should be the same).

Update:  Decided to throw in a video filter and use the command line instead of python as a sanity check.  Still, out.mp4 is showing as 1920x1072 when I inspect the files property details via Windows Explorer.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i test.jpg -vf scale=1920:1080 -t 1 out.mp4
```

This seems to be a strange bug unfortunately.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that `ffprobe` reports a wrong resolution after you've converted the video with `ffmpeg`. You could check with `mediainfo` or VLC. Also the glitch doesn't sound like it has **anything** to do with resolution but rather the length or timestamps of your videos.

Comment: You are right... I think it's a bug in Windows. The default pixel format is yuv444p, and the [property show 1920x1072](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgTkx.png). When setting pixel format to yuv420p [property show 1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjI5j.png). Command: `ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i test.jpg -vf scale=1920:1080 -t 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`.